# DbContext design MVC 5 EF 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to MVC and EF so this question might seem dumb to experienced MVC people so I apologize.

I am creating an MVC 5 / EF 6 app that has 6 tables not including the ASPNET Identity tables.

Would it be a better design to have one DB Context with all the tables or should I seperate the tables into their own contexts? I want to Scaffold each table into directories with their CRUD views not sure if I can do that with one DB Context. Also I tried doing seperate contexts but it threw fits when I tried doing migrations.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you handle migrations? I tried setting up multiple and it blew up.

Comment: You will need to specify the migration by context name, EX enable-migration mydbcontext ...

Comment: I'm a desktop developer (`WPF`) and I'm just wondering how you'll do joins and use the true potential of `EF` by having tables in separated contexts. That doesn't make any sense for me.

Comment: Having separate DB context for each table/model is pointless. Your DB context should represent the tables in your database including their relations.

Comment: Would it make sense to separate each page of a story into its own book?

Answer (score 0):

i was building my CMS using ASP.NET MVC5 with 2 dbContext (1 for identity and another for as my main database tables).. It's seems like it's not well done when working with different dbContexts. Sometime updating database fail telling that there is another instance of migration in another dbContext that be consider first (this was wrong because that i already updated the database ). Sometime there was a need to update both database context to get the correct migration implemented. It's really not funny. May be i was not doing it well but i thing that you should have less problems and conflit using only one dbContext And can be of help when using join in query as relational database. And you **lose a lot of flexibility** and the **advantage** of the entity Framework when using many dbContexts.